# How can I hide the artboard labels in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I have a bunch of artboards set up that I need to edit, but the labels are all overlapping making it impossible to know what's going on. How do I hide them?

[image: example screenshot]

Edit: I've hidden the blue dots with View > Hide Edges, but can't find where to hide the grey labels.

Comment: How about a script that records their position that can then be used to delete them when you dont need them and then reinstate them later as needed?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to hide the labels entirely, however I can suggest you rename them and use some small symbol like "." for names, thus the labels will be very small and probably obscure the artwork less:

For that Goto to Window-> Artboards and then you can rename the artboards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to hide the labels.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem above @sanjaypoyzer, have you tried pressing Shift+O  (O for oscar) - that should hide bounding boxes for art boards labels when you don't need them.